# react native encoding conversion

Tags: encoding, react-native, buffer, iconv

I'm trying to convert a fetch response from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in react native.
I found this answer : [Encoding conversion of a fetch response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412253/encoding-conversion-of-a-fetch-response) but in react native i'm having some troubles...

I didn't manage to use iconv, i tryed :

```
npm install --save iconv-lite // success
```

then i do

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite') // Error 500 from react native
```

I didn't manage to use Buffer, it is unknown by react native and

```
require('buffer').Buffer // Error 500 from react native
```

So here are my questions :

What is the best way to make an encoding conversion in react native ?
In case [Encoding conversion of a fetch response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412253/encoding-conversion-of-a-fetch-response) is good: How do i use iconv ? How do i use Buffer ?

Comment: have you checked this github thread already?

https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/150

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this code:

```
import iconv from "iconv-lite";
import {Buffer} from "buffer";

let str = iconv.decode(Buffer.from("hello"), 'us-ascii')
```