# How to solve encoding problem of fetch response in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I was using react native 0.48.3 and getting response from fetch request i don't see any encoding problem  it resolves by itself the encoding problem because the content-type of my response is : application/json;charset=iso-8859-1 . Now i upgraded my react native app to 0.59.8 i don't know why fetch doesn't resolve encoding problem anymore althought it's the same code . I have just upgraded my app . Do you have any idea  ? Here is my fetch code :

```
export const setDocumentListDataAsync = (k, action, server) => {
 return () => {
  fetch(defineUrlForDocumentList(action, server), {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers:{
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  })
  .then(
  (response) => {
    var contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
    console.warn(contentType)
      return response
    }
    ).then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: so server responses does not match that you expect? when you pass `Content-Type` in request you just define that for request, not response.

Comment: ^ when you set the header to `utf-8`, fetch probably expects the response to be `utf-8` and decodes incorrectly.

Comment: yup . So how can i force it to convert response type  to utf-8 ? And do you think that the version of react js affects the manner that works fetch ?

Comment: @Avin even when i remove headers i get the same problem

Comment: Not 100% sure what's going on, but you can try passing the response through an array buffer and decoding it with your own library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412253/encoding-conversion-of-a-fetch-response

Comment: Yeah, fetch uses whatwg-fetch  v1 in 0.48 and whatwg-fetch v3 in the current master branch.

Comment: @AvinKavish so what you advise me to do ?

Comment: Check the link.

Comment: trying the link gives me this error FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do this :

```
export const setDocumentListDataAsync = (k, action, server) => {
 return () => {
  fetch(defineUrlForDocumentList(action, server), {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers:{
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  })
  .then(
  (response) => {
    var contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
    console.warn(contentType)
      return response.json()
    }
    ).then((myJson) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you mahdi but doesn't change the problem of encoding

Comment: Suppose the server only supports iso-8859-1 encoding, no matter what; that code won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iconv-lite` to deal with the `iso-8859-1` encoding.
Since you need to fetch an ArrayBuffer and React Native doesn't support `response.arrayBuffer()` you can use the [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) as a workaround.

Here is an example:

```
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

const fetchJSON = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onload = () => {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(iconv.decode(Buffer.from(request.response), 'iso-8859-1')));
            } else {
                reject(new Error(request.statusText));
            }
        };
        request.onerror = () => reject(new Error(request.statusText));
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        request.open('GET', url);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=iso-8859-1');
        request.send();
    });
}

export const setDocumentListDataAsync = (k, action, server) => {
    return () => {
        return fetchJSON(defineUrlForDocumentList(action, server))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

You should also install the packages `buffer` and `stream`.

Answer (score -1):

Might be an old question, but this issue can be easily solved using the arrayBuffer() function of the fetch() response. Had a similar issue, where the server returns data in ISO encoding. Fetch .text() automatically converts the response to UTF-8 and that leads to encoding issues.

Full solution described here: https://schneide.blog/2018/08/08/decoding-non-utf8-server-responses-using-the-fetch-api/

Comment: This is not possible in react-native as arrayBuffer is not implemented.