# Fetching and decoding non-utf8 data (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, utf-8, axios, iso, text-decoding

I have a react native project, in which I am trying to fetch an html page and parse it, in order to display some of its content.

I originally performed the request with react's fetch api. However, the page that I got was encoded using the ISO-8859-7 charset, as noted by the header 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-7' that was present in the response, and several characters were malformed (as in '????'). Looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), I found that:

> the response is *always* decoded using UTF-8

Thus, I tried performing the request with the XMLHttpRequest api, in conjunction with [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite), as noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450474/11610972) answer. However, the characters were still not being displayed correctly.

Next, I tried performing the request with axios, using iconv ([ref](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/332)), and then using the [iso-8859-7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-8859-7) npm package ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211246/encoding-issue-with-axios)) for decoding, to no avail still.

After that, I tried performing the request with superagent, using its [charset plugin](https://github.com/magicdawn/superagent-charset), (again using iconv and iso-8859-7 npm packages for decoding, separately) but the characters were yet again '????'.

I also tried setting the 'Accept-Charset' header to 'utf-8' in all requests I performed, but that did not change the response at all. The only way the html page is displayed correctly apart from a web browser is via Postman, although I don't see anything special in Postman's request headers.

Here is an abstract pseudocode of the procedure I followed with the packages mentioned:

Iconv:

`performRequest().then(response => iconv.decode(Buffer.from(response.data)))`

ISO-8859-7 package:

`performRequest().then(response => iso88597.decode(response.data))`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** Versions of packaged used:

`"react-native": "^0.63.3"`

`"react": "16.13.1"`

`"axios": "^0.21.0"`

`"iconv-lite": "^0.6.2"`

`"superagent": "^6.1.0"`

`"superagent-charset": "^1.2.0"`

`"iso-8859-7": "^1.0.0"`

Comment: Is any database involved?

Comment: No, there is no database in the picture.